# Why is my Split array throwing errors when i try to put the elements into cells?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm writing a program to parse through a large text file with multiple incredibly long arrays that are saved in one line using commas to break.

```
<valueslist list="-213.054,-200.3051,-193.7893,-185.3383,-186.351,-186.797,-185.2577,...
```

I'm using the split function to try and break it up but when I try to execute my program it throws out `Run-Time error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error`

```
If InStr(Text, "<valueslist list=") <> 0 Then

    Column = 5
    Text = Replace(Text, "<valueslist list=" & Chr(34), "")
    Text = Replace(Text, Chr(34) & "/>", "")
    wrdArray = Split(Text, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(wrdArray)
        Cells(Row, Column).Value = wrdArray(i)
        Column = Column + 1
    Next i
    Row = Row + 1

End If
```

When I try to debug it takes me to

```
Cells(row, column).Value = wrdArray(i)
```

I have this code inside a loop but it dies about half way through my file when the arrays that I'm trying to parse become massve

Comment: A SHOT IN THE DARK : `...that I'm trying to parse become massve` Debug `UBound(wrdArray)` and see what is the value. Excel 2003 has 256 columns and Excel 2007+ has 16384 columns. if your `column` is greater than the limit then you will get an error.

Comment: If `column` is within limits then use error handling to find the value of `i` and check what is the value of `row`, `column` and `wrdArray(i)`

Comment: That was definitely it, they array was going on 32k at that point. Thanks a ton

Comment: @SiddharthRout,  can you add that as an answer?  Helps those of us looking for unresolved issues.

Comment: @Byron: I understand. Done as requested.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a postmortem report :P

> I have this code inside a loop but it dies about half way through my file when the arrays that I'm trying to parse become massve

Since it is becoming massive then there is a possibility that your code is trying to write to columns which do not exist in Excel.

If you are using `Excel 2003` then you can only write to `256` columns and if you are using `Excel 2007+` then the limit is increased to `16384`.

Best way to check if the limit is being reached or not is to debug the line `UBound(wrdArray)`

OP finally checked and confirmed that array was going on 32k at that point.